# Delete duplicated mysql rows with no primary key

Tags: mysql

Hi i have a mysql table without primary key and i need to delete the duplicated rows. how can i do so?

```
user_id category_id
1            2
1            3
1            4
1            2
2            2
2            3
2            2
```

Comment: duplicate `user_id` or duplicate `category_id` or complete row

Comment: Please show table definition. What is table's engine?

Answer (score 34):

```
 CREATE TABLE temp SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tablename;
 ALTER TABLE tablename RENAME junk;
 ALTER TABLE temp RENAME tablename;
```

Comment: i think it must be `DISTINCT(user_id)`

Comment: @diEcho the OP asked for distinct rows - not distinct user_id.

Comment: @Damian :-) cool glad it works for you. Oh side note - you will lose any other indexes on your original table if you have them.

Comment: I agree with @adiran-cornish , you should copy the create statement of your table from a tool like workbench and use that create statement to retain the original table indexes

Comment: Saved me a lot of hassle bending my brain on how to do this by simulating row_number() and using group by, which I stopped trying to do now I know of :)

Comment: It's works, but I guess that SQL code is better: CREATE TABLE temp SELECT * FROM _potential_members GROUP BY `personkey`;

Comment: Why is this upvoted? It does not copy any other constraints, foreign_keys on the table, just the values. Not a clean solution imho.

Comment: This solution will not work if rows have any null values

Answer (score 5):

Since you cannot differentiate 2 identical rows, you cannot delete just one of them. The way you need to think about it is like this:

```
insert into new_better_table
select user_id, category_id from old_table group by user_id, category_id
```

Comment: I think you could use a SELECT DISTINCT rather that a GROUP BY - not sure if there is an efficiency difference though.

Comment: Yeah. I generally prefer GROUP BY to DISTINCT because I find that it's more explicit and therefore clearer. I'm pretty sure performance will be identical on most (all?) systems. If there was ever a case to choose DISTINCT over GROUP BY... this is it. "DISTINCT *" is indeed much clearer than "GROUP BY [everything]". There's a big efficiency gain in the number of characters you need to type.

Comment: LOL :-) - am I right in thinking EXPLAIN wont work - be DBA pedant to know the answer which if any is better

Comment: I am terrible at ANSI SQL but I have a gut feeling DISTINCT is evaluated last - so GROUP BY might be more efficient - have to ask my friend who is a real DBA unlike me

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use a `dirty` flag with default value `1` and copy only single records with the flag set to `0`, then simply remove all dirty records. This way you don't need another table.

Assuming you already created a `dirty` flag with default value `1`:

```
insert into mytable
select fld1,fld2,fldN,0 as dirty
from mytable
group by duplicate_field
```

Then you can just delete dirty records:

```
delete from mytable where dirty = 1
```

Don't forget to remove the dirty flag. You're done.

Comment: clamiax the approach is really interesting but it will take too much time if records are too many like for table having record above 100000.

Answer (score 0):

The `select distinct *` solution proposed in another answer will not work in cases where your rows contain null values. A better solution that also prevents future duplicates from appearing in `my_table` in the first place is as follows:

```
create table no_dupes like my_table;
alter table no_dupes add unique index(unique_column,or_columns);
insert ignore into no_dupes select * from my_table;
rename table my_table to junk, no_dupes to my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using MariaDB and only this is working for me:

```
-- create and insert into temp table (only unique rows that will be deleted in the next query)
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_duplicates AS
SELECT user_id, category_id
FROM users_categories
GROUP BY user_id, category_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

-- delete duplicates
DELETE up1
FROM users_categories up1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, category_id
    FROM users_categories
    GROUP BY user_id, category_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS up2 ON up1.user_id=up2.user_id AND up1.category_id=up2.category_id;

-- insert unique only
INSERT INTO users_categories (user_id, category_id)
SELECT user_id, category_id
FROM temp_duplicates;

-- drop temp table
DROP TABLE temp_duplicates;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a MYSQL/MariaDB instance and did this similar to Adrian Cornish @990524. That reduced my dupes but I still had one record that was duplicated and couldn't be deleted for some reason, even if I tried to delete both. I solved it by doing it the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE temp LIKE tablename;
INSERT INTO temp SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE duped_id = '123' LIMIT 0,1;
INSERT INTO temp SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE duped_id != '123';
ALTER TABLE tablename RENAME junk;
ALTER TABLE temp RENAME tablename;
```