# How to remove duplicate data in a table(MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a table . In that I have inserted some duplicate data. I tried to delete the duplicate data from the table . But I can't. Please help me in this regard. It will be useful for my project.

I have attached my table content and the code which I tried.

Thanks in advance.

| Name | Age | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vaishu | 12 | CSE |
| Vaishu | 12 | CSE |
| Ammu | 21 | ECE |

[Code which I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq9VI.png)
[Errors which I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCIhl.png)

### EXPECTED OUTPUT

select * from information;

| Name | Age | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vaishu | 12 | CSE |
| Ammu | 21 | ECE |

Comment: consider using "select distinct".  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Don't store `age` in your table. In a year's time they will all be incorrect.

Comment: You might find this question more helpful - [Delete duplicated mysql rows with no primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8147076). If you want to do a delete, start by adding an id column to your table and populating it with something like `UPDATE DuplicateUsers du JOIN (SELECT @new_id := 0) vars SET du.id = (@new_id := @new_id + 1);`. Then make it PK and do delete based on ROW_NUMBER().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use CTE

```
WITH CTE(Name, 
    Age, 
    dept,
    DuplicateCount)
AS (SELECT Name, 
           Age, 
           dept, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name, 
                                          Age, 
                                          dept
           ORDER BY name) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM tbl)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1;

SELECT * FROM tbl
```

This will delete identical rows/rows...

Comment: You cannot delete from a CTE like that!

Comment: @nnichols may I know the reason?

Comment: The CTE is not updatable - `Error Code: 1288. The target table CTE of the DELETE is not updatable`

Comment: @nnichols I'm sorry, I overlooked the tag. Cause it works well in sql-server

Comment: Error Code: 1288. The target table CTE of the DELETE is not updatable. This error is coming when I try the above code which is shared by 'learning'. Please help me to solve.